# SSO with React Web Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am working on a React Application which needs to support SAML2.0. The need is to implement SSO with the Azure Active Directory, using Azure AD as an IdP.

I am trying to use this Library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js

But the thing I am unable to understand is where I can find the crt and pem file.

I have an application setup on the Azure AD, and I can access the fedration meta data. But I really don't know where the .pem and .crt file belongs to.

So far I have tried to implement SSO with Slack which is already listed in there gallery app so it is working.

Followed this Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/slack-tutorial%23configure-azure-ad-single-sign-on

I did not found any helpful guide which explains the SAML2.0 with React and Node.

So I need help for these two things.

1. How to integrate the Azure AD SAML Based Application to a React Application.
2. How to implement SSO with the SAML2.0 along with Azure AD.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: With new apps you should be using OpenId Connect and OAuth, not SAML. ADAL.js and MSAL.js can be used from JavaScript apps.

Comment: The SAML is requirement specific.

Comment: Hi @HarishSoni, how did you do it? I have the same requirement. Could you please assist me?